# AndroidStudio debug what is causing screen to refresh

Tags: android, android-studio

In android phones, Settings>Developer Options under the category Drawing there is an option called "Show surface updates" which make the entire window surface flash in a pretty pink color every time the a surface is redrawn.

With this option turned on I have an activity which isn't even blinking, its just pink because something is constantly redrawing. I have disabled all animations in this activity, yet something is still redrawing.

Is there a way to trace what is causing the redraw?

Comment: If you have more than one device, my first advice would be to reconfirm this under some other device too.

Comment: Already done. So the question remains. Is there a way to trace what causes the screen to update?